# Org-mode as a Get-Things-Done (GTD) system

Tags: org-mode, todo, remember

I use Org-mode as a structured notebook. I find it convenient to store information I want to keep using the directory/tree paradigm, when the notes I want to keep are too short to need a file.

I would now exploit my familiarity with Org and turn it in a Get-Things-Done (GTD) system.
While there is a specific section on [Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-gtd-etc.html) on [GTD](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-gtd-etc.html), it seems often  outdated.

Older articles ([2009](http://members.optusnet.com.au/%7Echarles57/GTD/gtd_workflow.html),
[2007](http://www.newartisans.com/2007/08/using-org-mode-as-a-day-planner/)) mention integration of Org with `remember-mode` for the implementation of GTD.  They mention a number of elisp variables/functions, e.g. `org-remember-store-without-prompt`, `org-remember-templates` and features such as "remember templates", which I am unable to find.

The Remember Mode entry in the [Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RememberMode) seems to clarify a bit:

> Now that OrgMode and RememberMode are included in Emacs (as of Emacs 23), activation is as simple as: (org-remember-insinuate)
> Note that there is no need for: (require 'remember)

but again I do not find `(org-remember-insinuate)`.

[Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2519301/1851270) mentions  yet another package, `(require 'org-remember)`, and still I have no such a library.

I am confused, to say the least. Outdated GTD guides on Worg might still be (conceptually) useful, but I need to have clear the following points.

- Is Remember mode still needed by Org? Or is its functionality entirely covered by Org?
- More specifically, is `org-capture` the Org alternative to Remember mode?

Comment: FWIW, I use Org for GTD too, and I followed this article: https://emacs.cafe/emacs/orgmode/gtd/2017/06/30/orgmode-gtd.html

Comment: @ManuelUberti: I read this. It does not mention Remember mode, but still details are missing and grounded on underlying assumption. E.g. `C-c c`  does not work out of the box. What package it depends on? Also `C-c C-c` works but says "can do nothing useful at this location".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than Googling for information, you can find up-to-date (usually) documentation for org-mode in the manual that ships with org-mode. Regarding `remember.el`, the manual notes:

> As of version 8.0, `org-remember.el` has been completely replaced by `org-capture.el`.

To answer your questions: remember is now part of `org-mode`, and no additional package is needed. `org-capture` has indeed replaced `org-remember`.

You can find all the details at the info node [(org) Capture](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html). I've linked to the online version, but it's better if you read it inside emacs, i.e. with `M-x org-info m capture <RET>`. The online version may not match the version of orgmode you're running. The version that ships with Emacs will always match your version of org-mode.

Answer (score 0):

org-capture must be set up prior to using it. Add the lines below to your .emacs file to set the default notes file and to set the keymap to use it.

```
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
```

Then you can follow the [Orgmode for GTD guide](https://emacs.cafe/emacs/orgmode/gtd/2017/06/30/orgmode-gtd.html).

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please edit your post to make your answer self-contained. We prefer to avoid link-only answers since the link could disappear at any time.

Comment: I edited my answer changing the first link for the instructions contained in it. Thanks for the tip.